Trouble Adding Custom CSS Classes to WordPress Menu Items in Twenty Twenty-Four Theme
I'm facing an issue with adding custom CSS classes to menu items in the Twenty Twenty-Four WordPress theme. I've tried using the nav_menu_css_class filter in the functions.php file of the theme, but the classes aren't being applied.
Here's the code I'm using in the functions.php file:

function add_custom_classes_to_menu_items($classes, $item, $args, $depth) {
    // Adding custom classes here
    $classes[] = 'my-custom-class';
    return $classes;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'add_custom_classes_to_menu_items', 10, 4);

Is there something specific to the Twenty Twenty-Four theme that could be causing this issue? Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this problem would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance for your help!
I've verified that the filter is correctly hooked and the callback function is being called, but for some reason, the classes aren't showing up in the menu items. When I switch to a different theme, the classes are applied as expected.
